# How to open port 9091 on a linux running under vmware?

Tags: linux, firewall, windows-7-x64, vmware-player

i have on my machine windows 7.

I installed vmware player and created a virtual machine running centos.

I installed Transmission on the centos.

Now i want to access it via web, like `http://111.111.111.111:9091`

9091 is the port of Transmission.

This port is showing closed.

So, how can i open that port so Transmission can conect?

where do i need to open it? On windows? On linux? On  router?

How i do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your router may be configured to route packets from the public network to the local machine in the private network. It needs 9091 port to be opened and routed to the private IP.

Moreover, you need to ensure that your router can [ping](/questions/tagged/ping) your [centos](/questions/tagged/centos) guest before.

If it can't ping, take care of the network settings of VmWare host, AKA (bridge|nat|private|...) network mode.